# How do i display format_interval?

Tags: 8, datetime

In Drupal 8 I am using

```
$date_service = \Drupal::service('date');
$options = drupal_map_assoc(array(900, 1800, 3600, 7200, 10800, 21600, 32400, 43200,
  64800, 86400, 172800, 259200, 604800, 1209600, 2419200), array($date_service, 'formatInterval'));
```

But this gives me error

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   You have requested a non-existent service "date". Did you mean one of
>   these: "theme.negotiator.system.db_update",
>   "entity.definition_update_manager", "date.formatter",
>   "update.post_update_registry", "update.post_update_registry_factory",
>   "access_check.db_update", "access_check.update.manager_access",
>   "update.manager", "update.processor", "update.fetcher", "update.root"?
>   in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 161 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-8.0.x-dev/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).

What wrong am i doing? Am i missing use class something like this use Drupal.... or something wrong in line `$date_service = \Drupal::service('date');`

Comment: There is no default service for date in drupal 8

Comment: In that case how do i use :
$options = drupal_map_assoc(array(900 , .... .... , 2419200), array($date_service, 'formatInterval')); ?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2207453 drupal_map_assoc has been removed from drupal 8

Comment: $options = array_map($callback, array_combine($my_array, $my_array)); you can use it :)

Comment: I was using $options = array_map($callback, array_combine($my_array, $my_array)); but it was not working, just now figured out i was not using proper $callback. Anyways thanks @Leopathu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My piece of working code:

```
$time_intervals = array(30, 3600, 10800, 21600, 43200, 86400, 172800, 259200, 604800, 1209600, 2592000, 5184000, 7776000);

$options = $this->build_options($time_intervals);
```

Also i have defined following function in the same class:

```
function build_options(array $time_intervals, $granularity = 2, $langcode = NULL) {
  $callback = function ($value) use ($granularity, $langcode) {
    return \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatInterval($value, $granularity, $langcode);
  };

  return array_combine($time_intervals, array_map($callback, $time_intervals));
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _i have defined function formatInterval_. The code you are showing defines a `format_interval()` function, and it is not even clear for which class you defined it (since the function is defined as `public function format_interval($interval, $granularity = 2, $langcode = NULL)`). You cannot surely add it to the class implementing the _date.formatter_ service, without hijacking Drupal core.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default service for date in drupal 8, but it has service for date formatter,
you could do that simply with following code,

```
\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date, 'date_text');
```

For more formatting check the [article](https://knackforge.com/blog/rajamohamed/formatting-way-date-time-displayed-drupal-8)

Answer (score 1):

The code contains two errors, since Drupal 8

- doesn't have any *date* service
- doesn't define any `drupal_map_assoc()` function

The equivalent of Drupal 7 `format_interval($interval, $granularity = 2, $langcode = NULL)` is [`\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatInterval($interval, $granularity = 2, $langcode = NULL)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3AformatInterval/8.0.x), which also works on Drupal 8.0.x.

If you need to write code that given an array like `[30, 60]` returns an array like `[30 => '30 seconds ago', 60 => '1 minute ago']`, this is the code I would use.

```
$time_intervals = [30, 3600, 10800, 21600, 43200, 86400, 172800, 259200, 604800, 1209600, 2592000, 5184000, 7776000];

$options = build_options($time_intervals);

function build_options(array $time_intervals, $granularity = 2, $langcode = NULL) {
  $callback = function ($value) use ($granularity, $langcode) {
    return \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatInterval($value, $granularity, $langcode);
  };

  return array_combine($time_intervals, array_map($callback, $time_intervals));
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your code. Using $time_interval = array(.....); & $options = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatInterval($time_intervals, $granularity = 2, $langcode = NULL);  is not working. I am missing something.

Comment: I updated the answer with the code I would use.

Comment: Thanks it works . Except for few minor changes like $options = $this-> build_options($time_intervals); Updating my working piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

For those who got here by searching how to use **formatInterval** to override a field value here is how it could be done:

```
$interval = time() - strtotime('time string loaded from entity');
$interval = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatInterval($interval, 2);
$output = t('Was found @interval ago', array('@interval' => $interval));
```

The solution above is multilingual friendly, translate the text in **User interface translation**